# Has someone come across this "can not find perl to execute ./installer" when installing veritas on centos 7

Tags: linux, unix, system-administration

while trying to run the veritas 7.4.2 installation script(./installer) on a centos 7 server, i get this message in return "can not find perl to execute ./installer". how can i bypass this ?

Comment: Have you considered installing perl?

Comment: yes i did but the instill script would not execute

Comment: Perl might be installed, but is it accessible via your PATH variable?  If you type `which perl` it should return the directory where your perl executable is found.  If it returns nothing, perl is not found under the directory included in your PATH.  You will have to adjust your PATH accordingly.